# How to network kivy apps

Tags: python, kivy

I'm working on a project involving creating a Hospital Management System with kivy because i hate working with web frameworks. What is the best way i can achieve this by networking kivy apps on different pcs to connect to a single database

Comment: A RESTful API and HTTP calls?

Comment: no, i dont want to use that, cant i just create a shared folder where the databse will be kept which can be accessed by all the pcs?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how databases work... Nor have you mentioned *what database*

Comment: An sqlite database

Comment: Sqlite databases aren't hosted on a network, but if they were, you'd still want a webserver that hosts an API layer over it... Honestly, that's the "best way" to get different devices to connect to a "single database". Or you could look into Firebase real-time database, for example (not sure about Kivy support)

Comment: install a mysql server on the pc you want to be the server.

Comment: Ok,, I'll try that

Comment: i'm working on an app that connects to a firebase real-time database using kivy's URLrequest module. Haven't deployed it yet, but firebase has worked when others haven't (using MacOS and iOS), definitely recommend using it. not too difficult to set up

Answer (score 1):

Since have you stated you want to work with **sqlite3** just put it in a shared folder somewhere and **open a connection from each kivy app**

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(r'\\some_host\some_shared_folder\example.db') #a drive map/mount will be helpful here as well ...
... 
#some kivy code that uses the connection above ...
```

sqlite3 supports multiple connections, though it will be slow ...